# trying to create object inside array of an object react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have tried to research this and i cant seem to figure this out.
So i have this function

```
const addWork = () => {
    setWorkArray([...workArray, { id: uniqid(), company: '', title: '', dateFrom: '', dateTo: '', desc: [], editing: true }]);
};
```

this adds an object to my workArray, I'm trying to figure out how to add an object to the desc array. I think I'm on the right track I just can't figure out the below function properly.

```
const addWorkDesc = (itemId) => {
    let f;
    const inOf = workArray.filter((item, index) => {
        f = index;
        return item.id == itemId;
    });
    setWorkArray({ ...workArray, ...workArray[f].desc, desc: [{ id: uniqid(), item: '', editing: true }] });
};
```

basically the workArray would look like this when im trying to push an object into the desc array

```
[
   { 
      id: 1asd5y, //generated with uniqid()
      company: 'some company', 
      title: 'peon', 
      dateFrom: 'fall 2012', 
      dateTo: 'spring 2014', 
      desc: [
             { 
                 id: 5d554ty, //generated with uniqid() 
                 item: 'some text here', 
                 editing: true 
              },
              { 
                 id: 9s9d87f, //generated with uniqid() 
                 item: 'some text here', 
                 editing: true 
              },
             ], 
      editing: true 
   },
   { 
      id: 0s09d8f, //generated with uniqid()
      company: 'some company', 
      title: 'peon', 
      dateFrom: 'fall 2012', 
      dateTo: 'spring 2014', 
      desc: [
             { 
                 id: 34kjh5, //generated with uniqid() 
                 item: 'some text here', 
                 editing: true 
              },
              { 
                 id: 77cvb7, //generated with uniqid() 
                 item: 'some text here', 
                 editing: true 
              },
             ], 
      editing: true 
   },
]
```

Comment: I want to makes sure I understand correctly. You have an array. You want to useState to update that array with an new item that is an object. Then you want to update that array item you just added, with a new property to that item that is also an array?

Comment: updated question to show how the data is suppose to look

Comment: What do you get from the function you have now? Nothing?

Comment: its not posting the data and giving me a .map() is not a function error

Comment: are you using a array.filter or an array.map?

Comment: im using map to render the content of the and filter to find and create a desc obj when a button is clicked

Comment: if it makes a difference i commented out the .map section so nothing renders and i created a button to console log the workArray and see nothing has been created

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is less elegant than your solution, but gets the job done.

```
let workArray = [];

const addWork = () => {
  workArray = [
    ...workArray,
    {
      id: "a",
      company: "",
      title: "",
      dateFrom: "",
      dateTo: "",
      desc: [],
      editing: true,
    },
  ];
};

const addWorkDesc = (itemId) => {
  let newWorkArray = [];
  workArray.forEach((item) => {
    if (item.id === itemId) {
      item.desc.push({ id: "aa", item: "", editing: true });
    }
    newWorkArray.push(item);
  });
  workArray = newWorkArray;
};

addWork();
console.log(workArray);
addWorkDesc("a");
console.log(workArray);

logs -> [
  {
    id: 'a',
    company: '',
    title: '',
    dateFrom: '',
    dateTo: '',
    desc: [],
    editing: true
  }
]

then 

logs -> [
  {
    id: 'a',
    company: '',
    title: '',
    dateFrom: '',
    dateTo: '',
    desc: [ [Object] ],
    editing: true
  }
]
```

Comment: sorry, thats replacing my entire array with this single object { id: uniqid(), item: '', editing: true }, it needs to add to desc array

Comment: oop! You did change the typo I had in the last line to `setWorkArray(newWorkArray)` Yes?

Comment: I guess it didn't work :(

Comment: sorry, no, but it gave me an idea, but i cant get it to work either

Comment: so odd, this the array I have after running `addWork()` then addWordDesc('a') ```[
  {
    id: 'a',
    company: '',
    title: '',
    dateFrom: '',
    dateTo: '',
    desc: [ [Object] ],
    editing: true
  }
]```

Comment: What did that code do for you that is different from what you wanted?

Comment: yes, sorry, apparently i didn't refresh, thats what i came up with too for the most part from your original example, i will mark this correct, thank you